# Showing Data FROM stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [Deal].[USP_LoadDealHistoryByDealId]
    (@DealId int,
     @chk int)
AS
    if(@chk = 1)
BEGIN 
SELECT 
        DDT.FieldType AS field,
        DDT.OldValue as old,
        DDT.NewValue as new,

        AU.FullName AS Name,
     DU.CompanyName As MarchentName ,
        DDT.UpdateOn AS UpdatedOn

FROM [Deal].[DealTransaction] as DDT
Inner Join  AD.Users as AU
on AU.UserId =DDT.[UpdateBy]
INNER JOIN dbo.UserProfile as DU 
ON DDT.[UpdateBy]= DU.ProfileID
where DDT.dealId=@DealId

END

ELSE if(@chk=2)
BEGIN 
SELECT 
        'No Data' as field ,
        0 as old ,
        0 as new ,
         AU.FullName AS Name,
     DU.CompanyName As MarchentName,
        DD.UpdatedOn AS UpdatedOn

FROM  AD.Users as AU
INNER JOIN [Deal].[Deals] AS DD
ON AU.UserId=DD.UploadedBy
INNER JOIN dbo.UserProfile as DU 
ON DD.UploadedBy= DU.ProfileID
where DD.dealId=@DealId
END
```

I have 4 tables (`Deal.Deals`, `deal.DealTransaction`, `AD.User`, and `dbo.UserProfile`). I want to union between two column `AU.FullName AS Name`, `DU.CompanyName As MarchentName` in same column and another. The problem is if I search deal `ID` the result comes only `UserId`-wise but when I search deal `ID` that contains UserProfile `ID` result did not come.. Is there any problem with the joining?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add what is your expected result,current result ,question is not clear

Comment: Please look at this link to improve it :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Does it work outside of the stored procedure?